# Feynman diagrams - How to push labels further?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, labels, tikz-feynman

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[border = 3mm, varwidth = 141mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{feynman}
\node[shape = circle, fill = black, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 20pt] (m) at (0, 0) {};
\vertex (a) at (225:1.5cm) {};
\vertex (b) at (-45:1.5cm) {};
\vertex (c) at (135:1.5cm) {};
\vertex (d) at (45:1.5cm) {};
\diagram*{
(a) -- [photon, ,color = red, edge label' = {\color{black}$q_2$}] (m)
-- [photon, color = red, edge label' = {\color{black}$q_1$}] (c),
(b) -- [plain, edge label = $p_2$] (m)
-- [plain, edge label = $p_1$] (d),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

How can I push the labels a little further?

**EDIT**

Labels at the end of lines usually designate particles, but my $q$ and $p$ are momentum. So, I just need to push them slightly apart, but not to the end of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making slight changes the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{feynman}
\node[shape = circle, fill = black, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 20pt] (m) at (0, 0) {};
\vertex (a) at (225:1.5cm) {\(q_{2}\)};
\vertex (b) at (-45:1.5cm) {\(p_{2}\)};
\vertex (c) at (135:1.5cm) {\(q_{1}\)};
\vertex (d) at (45:1.5cm) {\(p_{1}\)};
\diagram*{
(a) -- [photon, ,color = red] (m)
-- [photon, color = red] (c),
(b) -- [plain] (m)
-- [plain] (d),};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

which places the labels at the ends of the lines. For reference see page 9 of [TikZ-Feynman documentation](https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-feynman/tikz-feynman.pdf).

It appears that some components are fixed to the midpoint of the line(s) which means that playing around with placements is required. Making the dimensions of the lines bigger will give more space between labels or some " try and see what happens" needs to be applied. In this view the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman} %[large]
\node[shape = circle, fill = black, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 20pt] (m) at (0, 0) {};
\vertex (a) at (225:2.0cm) {\(e^{+}\)};
\vertex (b) at (-45:2.0cm) {\(W^{+}\)};
\vertex (c) at (135:2.0cm) {\(e^{-}\)};
\vertex (d) at (45:2.0cm) {\(W^{-}\)};
\diagram*{
(a) -- [photon, color = red, edge label'=\(q_{2}\)] (m)
-- [photon, color = red, edge label=\(q_{1}\)] (c),
(b) -- [plain, edge label'=\(p_{2}\)] (m)
-- [plain, edge label =\(p_{1}\)] (d)};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

provides:
[image]

This graph keeps nearly the same dimensions as the original code provided in the question.

Comment: @Samane  With a larger size it could appear so, otherwise some shifting needs to be applied. An update with another option is given for viewing.